# Ruby HTTP POST form error

Tags: ruby, curl

A little help would be much appreciated.

When I do this with curl under Linux everything is ok:

```
curl --data "password=myPassW0&true=1" http://www.myserver.com/adminapi/admin.php?method=login
```

When I try in Ruby, something I mess and goes wrong:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'openssl'

uri = URI.parse("http://www.myserver.com")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

if uri.port == 443 then http.use_ssl = true end
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/adminapi/admin.php")
request.body = {'method' => 'login', 'password' => 'myPassW0', 'true' => '1'}
response = http.request(request)

puts response
```

Any idea where am I wrong? Thanks!

EDIT:

Just debugged it, with curl I get this raw data:

```
POST /adminapi/admin.php?method=login HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.21.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.15 libssh2/1.2.6
Host: localhost
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 35
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

password=myPassW0&true=1
```

But with ruby I get this, that is wrong:

```
POST /adminapi/admin.php HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection: close
Content-Length: 3
Host: localhost

passwordmyPassW0true1methodlogin
```

Comment: Please provide the error response you are receiving.

Comment: #<Net::HTTPInternalServerError:0x2b1920657db8>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no answer, just found a dirty solution myself, using:

```
uri = URI("http://www.myserver.com/adminapi/admin.php?method=login")
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'method' => 'login', 'true' => '1', 'password' => 'PassW0')
```